Snippets stopped working after updating Visual Studio
I have just updated Visual Studio 2022 from version 17.10.6 to the latest version (17.11.2) and noticed that my C++-snippets stopped working.
To make sure, I tested it on my laptop with the same result; the snippets appear in the Code Snippets Manager, but do not show up in the IntelliSense list.
Has anybody else experienced this and knows how to fix it?
The only related issue I could find was for C# and a checkbox with "Show new snippet experience (experimental)", but that does not exist for C++.
Thank you in advance!

Do they work if you start VS in /safeMode? Or ol' trusty: Repair Reinstall?

Repair did nothing. Starting in /safeMode, I get the following error: "The 'GlobalHubClientPackage' package did not load correctly. ..". I found a thread, but none of the solutions listed there work.

I have tested it and the same problem as yours did not occur. If you have a problem with IntelliSense, please try the following method to see if it works:
1: Make sure that the Auto list members and Parameter information options are checked in Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > General.
2: Delete the .vs folder located in the solution directory. Reopen the solution and Visual Studio will automatically rebuild the IntelliSense database.
3: Tools > Options > Text Editor > C/C++ > Advanced > IntelliSense section, set the Disable IntelliSense option to True, then click OK to save the changes. Re-find the Disable IntelliSense option and set it to False, then click OK to save the changes.
4: If the above does not work, try resetting the Visual Studio settings: Tools > Import and Export Settings > Reset all settings.

Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, none of the options solved the issue.

Since this problem is that IntelliSense does not list the corresponding code snippets, if the above method and repairing VS do not work, you may need to try uninstalling and reinstalling VS.

So I can't get snippets to work, no matter what. I tried reinstalling VS2022, reinstalling Windows (10 and 11), creating new snippets from scratch. Nothing works. I only have the Community Edition, so I can't downgrade. :(
